# Getting sub products from same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables, `table1` has end products and product parts, `table2` has a mapping between `table1.productid` and `partsid`. i.e.

```
table1
--------------------------------------------
productid    descrip    code   cost  ....etc
1235         product A   07     12.5 ......
789          labor       03     2.5  ....
839          part1       03     5    ....
```

and `table2` looks like

```
table2
--------------------------------------------
productid    partsID    quantity
1235         789          1
1235         839          2
2341         2315         2
.....
```

I need to select the end product that meets specific code and go pull up the parts from the part table and display like below:

```
Resuls
--------------------------------------------
productid    descrip    code   partsID    cost ....etc
1235         product A   07    789        2.5  ......
1235         product A    03    839       5    ....
.......
```

Basically for each end product, line up the parts to the right and cost and all other details associated with the parts and not the end product.

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Can this progress more than 1 level? In other words could you also have a row in table 2 for product 839 and some other partsID that should be returned. I am thinking that this might a case for a recursive cte.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not join the Two tables across ProductID field:

```
SELECT * FROM 
dbo.TABLE1 o INNER JOIN
dbo.TABLE2 t ON o.ProductId = t.ProductId
WHERE o.code = 7
OR o.code = 3
etc ... whatever additional criteria you need
```

If you also need to Join the partsID you could say

```
AND o.PartId = t.partsId
```

Comment: Pretty sure you would want your where predicate to be "Where ProductID = 1235". As posted this will never return any rows because no value of code could be both 07 and 03 at the same time.

Comment: "end product that meets specific code"  It's hard to say with the information he provided.  It's not particularly clear.  But I changed the `AND` to an `OR`

Comment: hehe "not clear" is an understatement. I think your answer sounds as good as anything based on the very vague requirements. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to get something like this query, but I'm not sure about the code=07, you've specified in the example. Probably the code must be 03 for both parts.

```
SELECT 
    prd.productid,
    prd.descrip,
    prt.code,
    prdprt.partsID,
    prt.cost,
    ....etc
FROM table1 prd
JOIN table2 prdprt ON prd.productid=prdprt.productid
JOIN table1 prt ON prdprt.partsID=prt.productid
WHERE prd.code in ('07', ...othecodes) --if you filter by product's code
    OR prt.code in ('03', ...othecodes) --if you filter by parts's code
```